# Application of the Accept Header in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to insert an Accept header in the json file. But I don't know why the test does not work. Can you help me? Here is my code:

```
function doJSONRequest(type, url, headers, data, callback){
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
if(type && url && headers && callback && (arguments.length == 5)){
    r.open(type, url, true);
    if((type != "GET") && (type != "POST") && (type != "PUT") && (type != "DELETE")){
        throw new Error('The value is not recognized')
    } else if((type == "POST") || (type == "PUT") || (type == "GET") || (type == "DELETE")) {
        try {
            if(data === undefined) {
                data = null;
            }
            else if(typeof data === 'object'){
                r.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            } else {
                throw new Error("The data is undefined")
            }
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("The data has no JSON format")
        }
    } else if((type == "POST") || (type == "PUT")){

        r.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        r.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
```

And here is the test I use:

```
var expectedGETHeader = {
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

doJSONRequest("GET", baseUrl, headers, null, callback1);

setTimeout(function(){
    QUnit.start();
    assert.deepEqual(requests[4].requestHeaders, expectedGETHeader, "should set the \"Accept\": \"application/json\" header for GET requests");
},100);
```

Can you help me passing it? The specific error is:

```
should set the "Accept": "application/json" header for GET requests
Expected:   
{
    "Accept": "application/json"
}
Result:     
{}
Diff:   
{
     "Accept": "application/json"
} {}
```

SOLUTION
Adding the line of code after opening it
     r.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the `Accept` header getting set anywhere. Maybe you could do that right before calling `r.send(JSON.stringify(data));`, like so:

```
        if(data === undefined) {
            data = null;
        }
        else if(typeof data === 'object'){
            r.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); // <-- this was added
            r.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
            throw new Error("The data is undefined")
        }
```